# integration of continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=1$

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f$ be continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=1$. Let $G(a)=\frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$.

1.$\lim_{a\to 0} G(a)=\frac{1}{2}$

2.$\lim_{a\to 0} G(a)=1$

3.$\lim_{a\to 0} G(a)=0$

4.$\lim_{a\to 0} G(a)$ does not exist

is option 2 is correct using L'Hospitals rule?

Comment: Use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to get the desired limit equal to $f(0)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\lim_{a\to 0} G(a) = \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{\int_0^{0+a} f(x)\ dx - \int_0^0 f(x)\ dx}{a} = \left[\frac{d}{da} \int_0^a f(x)\ dx\right](0)$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. But it is simpler to use the definition of derivative of $G$.